# backup storage with blade server

Tags: backup, bladecenter

If say I have a BladeCenter S chassis and 2x BladeCenter Server HS22. I want to have a backup storage with this two.. what should I buy? what are my options? does it have to be IBM products? or any disk will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BladeCenter S](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/bladecenter/hardware/chassis/blades/index.html) is designed to integrate an optional [SAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network), but adding the option is [costly](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/bladecenter/hardware/chassis/blades/upgrades.html).

The [HS22](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/bladecenter/hardware/servers/hs22/index.html) blades support internal [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI) drives but those slots will accept standard [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA#SATA_and_SCSI) drives instead.

SAS drives have [definite advantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI#SAS_vs_SATA) over SATA drives, but [cost more](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/bladecenter/hardware/chassis/blades/upgrades.html).

Another option is to backup the disks in your blades across the network to some inexpensive system with lots of hard drives.

It's also possible to have the bootup hard drives for the blades somewhere else across the network using [iSCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI). Linux [supports iSCSI](https://serverfault.com/questions/13119/what-are-the-choices-for-iscsi-target-support-for-linux), so you could buy a cheap desktop, install Linux and a bunch of drives and the blades could mount those drives via iSCSI, using them for either system drives or backup drives.

If I've left out anything, I would be happy to clarify.